# How to check if element of class array is empty?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, null

Originally I did

```
entity * Ptr[8] = { NULL, };
```

But when I bring  Ptr to another function by reference using

```
updateMap(&mapGrid, Ptr); //and
void updateMap(map * mapGridU, entity * entityPtr) //then
if (entityPtr[i] != NULL)// gives an error
```

It says no operator "!=" matches these operands of entity and int

Comment: what does `entity * Ptr[8] = { NULL, };` means?

Comment: `entity * entityPtr` -> `entity ** entityPtr`. (I bet that's not the *only* error you get. In C++ don't immediately solve errors one by one, first try to approach them holistically)

Comment: If the error is not on `updateMap(&mapGrid, Ptr);`, your compiler needs higher conformance flags pronto.

Comment: (Somewhat OT: That code looks like C, not (modern) C++. With modern C++ I bet the problem wouldn’t even exist in the first place (resizable containers, `std::optional`, etc.).)

Comment: @appleapple It's the parent class that's abstract

Comment: @JirikaiNaito Oh yes. Not thought `entity` is type name. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The subscript operator indirects the pointer operand. The result is the value pointed by the pointer incremented by the integer operand.

Since `entityPtr` is `entity *`, it points to an `entity` object. Therefore the `entityPtr[i]` operation results in an lvalue of type `entity`. Since you're comparing that `entity` object with `NULL`, there must be an inequality operator that can take a `entity` and a pointer constant `NULL` as arguments. Your errors says that no such operator exists.

I suspect that your intention was something other than to compare the pointed `entity` object to `NULL`. My suspicion is that you intended to compare some pointer to `NULL` instead.